# How deploy springboot maven project in nexus with dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I create one project(component) with springboot and put some dependency in my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>br.com.myApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>nf</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-${project.release}</version>
    <name>nf</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <project.release>SNAPSHOT</project.release>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>repo</id>
            <name>Repositório</name>
            <url>https://myRepo.com/repository/repos/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-tracing-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <project.release>SNAPSHOT</project.release>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <project.release>RELEASE</project.release>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>staging</id>
            <properties>
                <project.release>RC</project.release>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>br/com/myApp/nf/NfApplication.class</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and in my other project I put

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>br.com.myApp</groupId>
 <artifactId>nf</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

But in my second project the dependency of my first (hibernate-validator, jackson, resteasy) are not included.

So how can I include all dependency in my first project deploy?

tks

Comment: what do you mean not included? Can you share the error ?

Comment: Just put those dependencies in the `<dependencies>` tag of your second project.

Comment: @YuriG. all dependency from 1 project I wanna to be import automatic to second .

Comment: Imported to where? IDE? maven? built jar?  what are you trying to do and what is the error do you get?

Comment: @YuriG. the second project have one pom.xml and I put the dependency of my first project, today when I run my second project I got one NoClassDefFoundError from for example a jackson class

Comment: in other words the dependencies classes do not exist in your runtime classpath?  correct?

Comment: @YuriG. yes, if I put all dependency in the second project will works.. but I don't wanna this behavior

Comment: Can you share the pom of the second project, especially the plugins section ?